# IOnic Open facebook app

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to open facebook application iusing ionic.
This is my code:

```
var scheme = 'facebook://';
 appAvailability.check(
      scheme, // URI Scheme
       function() {  // Success callback
              Ti.API.debug('Facebook is available');
              window.open(scheme+url, '_system', 'location=no');
          },
          function() {  // Error callback
              Ti.API.debug('Facebook is not available');
          }
    );
```

but I have this error:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "facebook://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme facebook"

any idea?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

On Android scheme is

> com.facebook.katana

instead of

> facebook://

On iOS scheme is

> fb://

Comment: same error:
**-canOpenUrl: failed for URL: "fb://" -error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb"**

Comment: Any other suggestion?? please